# jQuery confirm box on page load

Tags: jquery, popup

I want a pop-up confirm box with yes or no option on page load. For example if click registration link from menu that will go to that page, on that page a pop-up window should be open with message like "Are you new user..?".. with Yes and No option, if they click yes then they should redirect to the another page ..? There is lot of examples for pop-up confirm message like

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
         //other options
    });
});
```

but no one for on page load ..Please help me guys..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for your help. But it will open another window, I want to open in same window..

Comment: I got it.. using "_self" attribute in window.open() function..

Answer (score 1):

Set the `autoOpen` to `true` as below and try

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: true
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 but i cannot believe OP didn't try it before posting question here